# XQuery script to create indexes

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am trying to create a script that create indexes for a **MarkLogic** database. Please note the indexs shown is only a small sampling of the scripts to be created.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";
declare namespace xdmpdb = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/database";

declare variable $databaseName as xs:string := "army-itam";
declare variable $os as xs:string := "http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_OperatingSystem";
declare variable $pe as xs:string := "http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_PhysicalElement";

declare variable $os_xml as node() :=
<range-element-index>
  <index>  
    <type>string</type>
    <name>Name</name>
  </index>
  <index>  
    <type>string</type>
    <name>Version</name>
  </index>  
</range-element-index>;

declare variable $pe_xml as node() :=
<range-element-index>
  <index>  
    <type>string</type>
    <name>Model</name>
  </index>
  <index>  
    <type>string</type>
    <name>Manufacturer</name>
  </index>
  <index>  
    <type>dateTime</type>
    <name>ModelTest</name>
  </index>
</range-element-index>;

declare function local:add-range-element-index($config as element(configuration), $dbname as xs:string, $namespace-uri as xs:string, $type as xs:string, $localname as xs:string)
{
try {
     let $dbid := admin:database-get-id($config, $dbname)
     let $range-index := admin:database-range-element-index($type, $namespace-uri, $localname, "http://marklogic.com/collation/", fn:false() )
     let $ExistingREindexes := fn:data(admin:database-get-range-element-indexes($config, $dbid)/xdmpdb:localname)
     let $config :=
        if ($localname = $ExistingREindexes) 
        then $config
        else admin:database-add-range-element-index($config, $dbid, $range-index)
     let $log := xdmp:log(fn:concat("ERI (", $localname, ") added"), "info")
     return $config
} catch($e) {
     (fn:concat("Error adding ERI: ", fn:string-join($localname,",")),xdmp:log(xdmp:quote($e)))
   }
};

declare function local:create-index($config as element(configuration), $namespace-uri as xs:string, $server as node())
{
try {
    let $log := xdmp:log(fn:concat("Creating indexs for (", $namespace-uri, ")"), "info")
    let $config :=
      for $results in $server//index
        let $type := xs:string($results//type/text())
        let $name := xs:string($results//name/text())
        return local:add-range-element-index($config, $databaseName, $namespace-uri, $type, $name) 
    return $config
} catch($e) {
     xdmp:log(xdmp:quote($e))
   }
};

declare function local:index-create($config as element(configuration))
{
try {
     let $config := local:create-index($config, $os, $os_xml)
     let $config := local:create-index($config, $pe, $pe_xml)
     return $config
} catch($e) {
     xdmp:log(xdmp:quote($e))
   }
};

let $config := admin:get-configuration()
let $config := local:index-create($config)
return admin:save-configuration($config)
```

When I run this script, it only creates one index from each xml list defined, either the first or the last one. When I check the logs, the `local:add-range-element-index` function states that it processed all elements.

Also, the log says that the second xml list repeats by the number of index elements, *example of log*.

```
2013-10-03 15:20:52.291 Info: App-Services: Creating indexs for(http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_OperatingSystem)
2013-10-03 15:20:52.634 Info: App-Services: ERI (Name) added
2013-10-03 15:20:52.712 Info: App-Services: ERI (Version) added
2013-10-03 15:20:52.712 Info: App-Services: Creating indexs for (http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_PhysicalElement)
2013-10-03 15:20:52.751 Info: App-Services: ERI (Model) added
2013-10-03 15:20:52.789 Info: App-Services: ERI (Manufacturer) added
2013-10-03 15:20:52.856 Info: App-Services: ERI (ModelTest) added
2013-10-03 15:20:52.856 Info: App-Services: Creating indexs for (http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_PhysicalElement)
2013-10-03 15:20:52.895 Info: App-Services: ERI (Model) added
2013-10-03 15:20:52.932 Info: App-Services: ERI (Manufacturer) added
2013-10-03 15:20:52.970 Info: App-Services: ERI (ModelTest) added
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your for loop in `local:create-index()` is creating a sequence of configs, one for each `$server//index`. Each of those is the original config plus what you added on that particular iteration of the loop.

When you do the `admin:save-configuration()`, you're actually passing it a sequence of configs and function mapping is causing `save-configuration()` to be called once for each config.

I'd declare `local:create-index()` to explicitly return `element(configuration)` to make sure it only returns one.

I'd also make use of `xdmp:set()` to overwrite `$config` in each iteration of the loop.

```
xdmp:set($config, local:add-range-element-index($config, ...))
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use `xdmp:set()` you could get the same effect with a recursive function.

Comment: I added the `xdmp:set()` command to the for loop return line in the local:create-index() function. I also put in code to export the $config into the logs.

Answer (score 0):

The [Roxy deployer](https://github.com/marklogic/roxy/wiki) will handle this and much more for you.